# Posix Character Sets difference between [[:blank:]] and [[:space:]]?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, posix, whitespace

On [this website](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/presentations/leap_regex/13.html) it says:

```
[[:blank:]]     space and tab characters
[[:space:]]     whitespace characters
```

What's the difference between space and tab characters and whitespace characters? To me, they almost seem the same.

Answer (score 20):

The `[[:space:]]` class is a superset of `[[:blank:]]` which additionally (apart from the space and tab of `[[:blank:]]`) includes

- the newline character (`\n`, line feed on Unix, ASCII code 10),
- vertical tab (`\v`, ASCII code 11),
- form feed (`\f`, ASCII code 12), and
- carriage return (`\r`, ASCII code 13).

... in the POSIX locale, that is.  Other locales may have additional space characters.

Comment: IOW, `[[:blank:]]` is _horizontal_ spacing characters only while `[[:space:]]` contains all horizontal and vertical spacing characters. See also `\h` vs `\s` in `perl` regular expressions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is `\r` a vertical spacing character?

Comment: Except for the _space_ character, the `[[:space:]]` characters in the POSIX locale are all control characters, so the behaviour will vary with the device they are sent to. CR moves the cursor/carriage back to the start of the screen/page so on its own is not really a vertical spacing character, but it's part of the CRLF sequence that is sent to ttys for a line-break so as such can be seen as vertical spacing.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires `[[:space:]]` to be a superset of `[[:blank:]]` (in any locale). http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html

Comment: See also: https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02479.html