# Grep Lines from File with spaces

Tags: linux, grep, whitespace, pcregrep

I have File which contains Records

```
qwe.google.com IN A 1.1.1.1
qwe.google.com   IN {uneven-space} A{space}1.1.1.1
qwe.google.com  IN     CNAME      asd.google.com
```

I need to grep all the lines which contains `IN A`, as it contains uneven spaces in between i am not able to do so.

Comment: Can `IN A` appear anywhere except exactly where you want to match on if? For example could a string containing `IN A` like `TIN APPLES` appear in your input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -E "IN[[:blank:]]+A" file
```

- `[[:blank:]]` matches spaces and tabs, similar to `[ \t]`

Comment: And assuming GNU grep: `grep -P 'IN\s+A' file`

Comment: Note that `[[:blank:]]` matches SPC and TAB in the C/POSIX locale, but potentially many more blank characters in others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
grep -E "IN +A" file
```

which will match (via [extended regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) one or more whitespaces between `IN` and `A`.

If there can be other forms of whitespace (namely tabs) in between `IN` and `A`, you may need to use a [character list or character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) instead of the simple space, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558246/are-blanks-spaces-and-tabs-part-of-a-string/558251#558251) for example.

Comment: Tried, but it misses all the rest of "IN <spaces><spaces>A" in result.

Comment: Can you edit your example to include these lines?

Comment: with BRE you can do: `'IN \+A'`

Comment: @pLumo, only with GNU BRE implementations or compatible. `\+` is unspecified in POSIX BRE. In POSIX BRE, it would be `\{1,\}` instead of `\+`.

Comment: The GNU trap once again. thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$2 == "IN" && $3 == "A"'
```

May be closer to what you want (look for internet A records in that output).

With `grep`:

```
grep -E '[[:blank:]]IN[[:blank:]]+A[[:blank:]]'
```

would be better than just

```
grep -E 'IN[[:blank:]]+A'
```

Which could match on a line like:

```
example.com   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:EXAMPLE.IN ALL"
```

for instance.

In any case, both `grep` commands would match on:

```
example.com   IN      TXT     "blah IN A bleh"
```