# How can I test if a string has any ASCII white space characters in it?

Tags: bash, text-processing, whitespace

How can I check if a string has any whitespace characters in it? I do not have to worry about things outside of ASCII for example unicode zero width characters etc. You can assume that the string is stored in a shell variable, e.g. `$string`.

Example of behavior:

`abc`  has a space so it would return true

`\tabc` has a tab so it would return true

`abc` has no whitespace chars so it should return false

```
abc
hello
```

has a line break so it should return true

---

A solution using any common command line utility (`sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `bash`) would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In POSIX sh syntax:

```
case $string in
  (*[[:blank:]]*) echo "string contains at least one character classified as blank";;
  (*[[:space:]]*) echo "string contains at least one character classified as whitespace (but not blank)";;
  (*) echo no character classified as whitespace;;
esac
```

`[:blank:]` is required to be a subset of `[:space:]`. `[:blank:]` is guaranteed to contain at least space and TAB and `[:space:]` at least space, TAB, NL, CR, FF and VT.

That's according to the encoding being used and character classification in the locale. On most systems all locales use a charset that is ASCII or a superset of ASCII (if we ignore MS-Kanji found on some BSDs in some Japanese locales where 0x5c is `¥` instead of `\` (and there's no `\` character!) but is otherwise a superset of ASCII for the rest).

If you wanted to check that `$string` contains at least one ASCII-encoded ASCII-whitespace even on EBCDIC-based systems, you'd need to specify the set by byte values or use `iconv` to convert theme from the current charset to ASCII:

```
ascii_whitespace=$(printf ' \r\n\r\f\v' | iconv -t ASCII)
# or
ascii_whitespace=$(printf '\40\11\12\13\14\15')
case $string in
  (["$ascii_whitespace"]) echo contains at least one ASCII whitespace;;
esac
```

(hoping that `\15` doesn't happen to be a newline on that system).

Comment: If I use a script file with the shebang set as `#!/bin/sh` and the variable set with `string="abc\nxyz"` it seems to incorrectly respond with `no character classified as whitespace`? I get the same behavior with AdminBee's answer. My full example script using this answer is here: https://gist.github.com/chrissound/762667fba754dc1a472a6386cca124f0

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, that variable doesn't contain a whitespace. It contains a backslash followed by a `n`. Use `string=$(printf 'abc\nxyz')` to get a newline character in there. Or `string=$'abc\nxyz'` with some `sh` implementations (will be in the next POSIX version). Or a literal newline.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski and note that `[[ "$string" =~ [[:blank:]] ]]` is bash syntax, not sh syntax (also supported by ksh93 (`[[...]]` comes from ksh) and zsh).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your string is stored in a shell variable `$string`. In that case, since you have indicated `bash` as the shell, you can use the builtin regular expression matching inside the `[[ ... ]]` test construct:

```bash
if [[ "$string" =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then echo "Contains whitespace"; else echo "Doesn't contain whitespace"; fi
```

The same can be used inside a shell script.

Some usage examples:

```shellsession
~$ string=" hello "
~$ if [[ "$string" =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then echo "Contains whitespace"; else echo "Doesn't contain whitespace"; fi
Contains whitespace

~$ string=$'\thello'
~$ if [[ "$string" =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then echo "Contains whitespace"; else echo "Doesn't contain whitespace"; fi
Contains whitespace

~$ string="hello"
~$ if [[ "$string" =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then echo "Contains whitespace"; else echo "Doesn't contain whitespace"; fi
Doesn't contain whitespace
```

**Note:** This uses the POSIX character class `[:space:]`. See e.g.

- [Posix Character Sets difference between [[:blank:]] and [[:space:]]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352630) or
- [Are Blanks, Spaces, and tabs part of a string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558246/377345)

for the subtleties between `[:space:]` and `[:blank:]`. If you only want to consider characters that create whitespace *within the same line* (i.e. `<space>` and `\t`), you should switch to `[:blank:]` instead (but note that in some locales, `[:blank:]` will also contain vertical space characters).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl6)

```
~$ echo "abc " | raku -ne '.contains(/ \s /).say'
True
~$ echo "abc" | raku -ne '.contains(/ \s /).say'
False
```

The above Raku code is run linewise over the input with the awk-like `-ne` command-line flags. Raku's `contains` method returns a boolean. The leading `.` dot on `contains` directs that input is taken off the command line, or (alternatively) **stdin**.

```
~$ echo "abc " | raku -ne 'say .contains(/ \s /) ?? True !! False;'
    True
~$ echo "abc" | raku -ne 'say .contains(/ \s /) ?? True !! False;'
    False
```

Above is slightly more complicated because it uses Raku's ternary operator: Test `??` True `!!` False . Raku has logical `True` and logical `False`, so no need to quote the above returns. The advantage here is you can simply replace `True` and `False` with double-quoted returns of your choosing, e.g. `"Yes"` and `"No"`.

Presumably the OP's question pertains to *horizontal* whitespace, and in that regard Raku can distinguish `\h` horizontal whitespace from `\v` vertical whitespace:

```
~$ raku -e 'put "abc\t";' | raku -ne 'say .contains(/ \h /);'
True
~$ raku -e 'put "abc\t";' | raku -ne 'say .contains(/ \v /);'
False
```

The OP doesn't say whether multiline input strings must be handled. They'll always be "positive" for whitespace, but possibly "negative" for horizontal whitespace. [Think of a column of numbers as input]. Anyway, in Raku you can read input in linewise as above (which autochomps by default), or all-at-once (retaining eol `\n` newlines) with the oddly-named-but-memorable `slurp`.

Reading linewise (autochomps):

```
~$ raku -e 'put "1\n2\n3";' | raku -ne 'say .contains(/ \h /);'
False
False
False
~$ raku -e 'put "1\n2\n3";' | raku -e 'for lines() {say .contains(/ \h /)};'
False
False
False
```

Reading all-at-once (no autochomping):

```
~$ raku -e 'put "1\n2\n3";' | raku -e 'say slurp.contains(/ \v /);'
True
~$ raku -e 'put "1\n2\n3";' | raku -e 'put slurp.contains(/ \h /);'
False
```

---

Addendum: I'm interpreting the OP's statement, *"I do not have to worry about things outside of ASCII..."* as *'I don't care if Unicode is handled or not'*. If ***only*** ASCII whitespace is to be handled (and all others rejected), that's something Raku can manage, but not addressed above. Note that Raku is Unicode-ready, so that `\s` (which is short for `<space>`) and `\h` (which is short for `<blank>`) as well as `\v` all accept Unicode by default.

If you want to reject non-ASCII (horizontal) whitespace, you could try something like the following bespoke character class: `<:ASCII> & <blank>`.

Examples:

```
~$ raku -e 'put "\xA0";' | raku -ne 'put .contains(/ <blank> / );'
True
~$ raku -e 'put "\xA0";' | raku -ne 'put .contains(/ <:ASCII> & <blank> / );'
False
```

---

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
[https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#\h_and_\H](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#%5Ch_and_%5CH)
https://docs.raku.org/routine/contains
https://raku.org